# OpenGL show object on the screen

Tags: c++, opengl

I just started learning OpenGL so I have problem with showing the object on the screen.

`Display()` contains this object and I want to show this one by `glutDisplayFunc(Display);` but it's not working, I have only grey screen after compiling. (Yeah, this object is wheel)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

GLint Width = 1024, Height = 640;

const int CubeSize = 500;


void Display (void) {
    glClearColor (0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3ub (255, 200, 200);


    int iTimeElapsed = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    float fRevolveScale1 = 0.2f;
    float fRevolveScale2 = 0.4f;
    long i;

    // clear all pixels
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // push temp state
    glPushMatrix();

    // translate to center
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0);

    // rotate around pivot
    glRotatef(iTimeElapsed * fRevolveScale1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // translate to planet location
    glTranslatef(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0);

    glRotatef(iTimeElapsed * fRevolveScale2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glColor3f(0.129412f, 0.129412f, 0.129412f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.1f, 16, 16);

    // five bolts, step 72 degree (72*5=360 degree)
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    for (i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(72.0f*i, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // rotate coordinate 72 degree
        glTranslatef(0.04f, 0.0, 0.0);// translate on the rotated coordinate
        glutSolidSphere(0.01f, 16, 16);
        glPopMatrix();
    }

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);// translate on the rotated coordinate
    glutSolidSphere(0.01, 16, 16);

    // pop temp state
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
    glutPostRedisplay();

    glFinish ();
}



void Reshape(GLint w, GLint h) {
    Width = w, Height = h;
    glViewport (0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glOrtho (0, w, 0, h, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity ();
}


void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    const char ESCAPE = '\033 ';
    if (key == ESCAPE) exit (0);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv []) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (Width, Height);
    glutCreateWindow("E X A M P L E");
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
    glutMainLoop ();
}
```

Comment: You have a redundant color clear. Is depth enabled? If so you should clear depth. You can try a tool such a RenderDoc to try and find whats going wrong with your application.

Comment: You should have a look at your transformations. If you set up a projection to establish a 1:1 pixel mapping, you shouldn't be surprised that spehres with radius of `0.1` or `0.01` pixels aren't visible.

Comment: @derhass i've tried to use `glutSolidSphere(16, 16, 16);` but it not working. Any size isn't working.

Comment: @derhass can I trouble you for giving me an example how to draw object and show it on the screen?

Comment: There are some tutorials like [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/index.html), [open.gl](https://open.gl/) or [opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/). These have some sections on the basics of the transformations and the math behind them. Additionaly, all of these explicitely teach "modern" OpenGL, in contrast to the almost 25 year old functionality you are using, which is _deprecated_ since 2008, and has been _completely removed_ from the modern core profile of OpenGL.